# android CardView alternative

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I was looking into Google's Material Design CardView, and love the concept, but realize that CardView was only available for devices running on Android 5.0 and up. Since I want to quickly deploy the new design our application, and do not want to wait until most devices are upgraded until 5.0, I was wondering if there would be any other alternative to CardView that would support devices from 4.0 and up.

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CardView` also with a lower API since it's supported. Simply add the following lines in your gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
}
```

Comment: I am still working eclipse, my current configuration are as follow    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449344/using-android-support-v7-widget-cardview-in-my-project-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look over there (using support library) :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24468117/4232337

As mentionned,

> The v7 Support Libraries r21 and above includes the following material design features:
>
> Material design styles for some system widgets when you apply one of the Theme.AppCompat
> themes.
>
> Color palette theme attributes in the Theme.AppCompat themes.
>
> The RecyclerView widget to display data collections.
>
> The CardView widget to create cards.
>
> The Palette class to extract prominent colors from images.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***androidx*** **CardView** dependency:

```
dependencies {
     implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
}
```