# Missing resources for Android CardView library

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-cardview

I'm using CardView in my project and I'm getting an error on older devices:

```
 E  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        E      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                        E      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
                        E      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
                        E      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
                        E      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
                        E      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
```

Seems similar to a few questions on SO such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449344/using-android-support-v7-widget-cardview-in-my-project-eclipse)

My problem is that the solution for that questions feels very hacky and that's understandable as the answer was given last year when Lollipop just entered the public preview. Have things changed since? How do I get the resources?

I've tried a few things such as importing .aar as a module but nothing seems to work. I've followed the official documentation on how to add support libraries (https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res) but that didn't work. Also according to that link - there doesn't seem to be any difference between adding libraries with and without resources for Android Studio?

My app build.gradle includes the following dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
```

CardView layout is used here

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        card:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        card:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        tools:ignore="NewApi">
```

EDIT: the problem noticed on Samsung S2 2.3 - API 19+ works fine

Comment: share xml code as well

Comment: added the xml for my cardview

Comment: which is line number 25 in your xml

Comment: that's the line for the cardview

Comment: strange issue cant help much on it just make sure you have also updated v4 library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?android:attr/selectableItemBackground` is platform related, use it without `android:` prefix to refer to AppCompat's attribute.

Comment: amazing, thank you so much!! do you have any reference to this in documentation? I obviously missed that part...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#selectableItemBackground