# android support(cardView, RecyclerView)library in older versions with target kitkat

Tags: android, android-support-library

Can we use `cardview-v7-21.0.0` library support libraries in older versions? How to use android support(cardView, RecyclerView)library in older versions in android by using eclipse.

Comment: Android Studio is the official IDE for Android development, and ADT is not supported anymore.

Answer (score 7):

As described in the official [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html):

> Each Support Library is backward-compatible to a specific Android API level.

For example the

- `support v4` : **minSdk=4**
- `v7 appcompat library`: **minSdk=7**
- `v7 recyclerview library`: **minSdk = 7**
- `v7 CardView library`: **minSdk = 7**

Today you can use the cardview-v7-22.1.0.

This support library is a library with resources. To setup in Eclipse you can follow the [official guide](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res).

Hovewer, I suggest you using [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

> If you have been using Eclipse with ADT, be aware that Android Studio is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate to Android Studio to receive all the latest IDE updates.

To setup in Android Studio just add this line in your dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it in lower version. Please view [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449344/using-android-support-v7-widget-cardview-in-my-project-eclipse).

Also you can use this [materiallist library.](https://github.com/dexafree/MaterialList) which supports card view upto 2.3+.

My suggestion would be to use Android studio as it is much easier to add libraries to it.