# Android -How to use RecyclerView in 4.0 API 14

Tags: android

I have implemented RecyclerView with CardView successfully. But now I want to support from API 14 also. Presently it looks like we need API 17 to support recyclerview.

Can anybody know is it possible to use RecyclerView in 4.0 OS or any other solution to this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But now I want to support from API 14 also. Presently it looks like we need API 17 to support recyclerview.

`RecyclerView` comes from the `recyclerview-v7` library, which works back to API Level 7.

Comment: Thank yo CommonsWare. It works when i used " compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'"

Answer (score 6):

According to CommonsWare answer, please read this guide: [Maintaining Compatibility](http://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html)

Here you would find:

> The `RecyclerView` and `CardView` widgets are available in earlier
>   versions of Android through the Android v7 Support Library with these
>   limitations:
>
> - `CardView` falls back to a programmatic shadow implementation using    additional padding.
> - `CardView` does not clip its children views that intersect with rounded corners.
>
> #### Dependencies:
>
> To use these features in versions of Android earlier than 5.0 (API
>   level 21), include the Android v7 Support Library in your project as a
>   Gradle dependency:
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
>     compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
>     compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
> }
> ```

Moreover in source code of [`RecyclerView`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java), you would find this line

> ```
>         if (className.length() != 0) {  // Can't use isEmpty since it was added in API 9.
>             className = getFullClassName(context, className);
> ```

I don't know a guy using API 9, but it seems to be that it's really well backward supported kibrary.

Check also: [android support(cardView, RecyclerView)library in older versions with target kitkat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29982535/android-supportcardview-recyclerviewlibrary-in-older-versions-with-target-kit)

Hope it help

Comment: Thank you Piotrek. It worked for me by adding below line

compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'

Answer (score 0):

No idea about supporting that official `RecyclerView` on 4.0 android, but there are always Librarys such as:https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview

Which those librarys can support these things, for example the above library can support this:

**Target platforms**

> API level 9 or later (However, some animations are not supported on Gingerbread.)