# SDK 19 and below is not recognising android.support.v7.widget.CardView , Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android, android-cardview, layout-inflater, backwards-compatibility

in my Xml file i have cardView

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="4dp"
android:paddingRight="4dp"
android:paddingBottom="2dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:id="@+id/channel_cardview"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="2dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

   .... some other elements here 
  </RelativeLayout>
```

when i run my app on SDK 23 it worked fine but when am running this on SDK 19 or SDK 16 then its not working and throwing  this error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at pb.pocketboard.ChannelFragment$ChannelsAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ChannelFragment.java:578)
    at pb.pocketboard.ChannelFragment$ChannelsAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ChannelFragment.java:537)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5482)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4707)
```

error is pointing to Line no. 10 which is of `cardViewCLass`, 
maybe system is not recognising the `Cardview` Class so i searched for related issues and there the problem was not adding the dependencies but i already added it

my Gradle :

```
dependencies {

compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:2.1.1'
compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.0.16'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.3@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
}
```

my java Class where i'm inflating the layout

```
    @Override
public ChannelsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_channel_row, parent, false); // error is here 
    ChannelsViewHolder holder = new ChannelsViewHolder(rowView , this);

    return holder;
    }
```

any clue why is this happening  ??

Comment: I think it should be something related to memory usage... http://stackoverflow.com/a/23202156/2442831 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680451/inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-1-error-inflating-class-unknown-cause

Comment: @Lino i checked that question before but here am not allocating any memory

Comment: can you please attach your build.gradle (Module:app) file in the case when your application is throwing error.

Comment: the whole gradle file ? @AmitUpadhyay cause i already added the dependency section

Answer (score 2):

CardView is added in the lollipop version. The same problem will occur when you will try to use RecyclerView ( or any other View that has been added in API 20 (v5.0) or later). Although they are added in support library.

Now once you give a thought that **why have they been added to support library?**

Its because developers can use them in older versions of android mobiles **not because the developer can use them in older versions of SDK**. Basically the developer is always going to develop the applications on the updated SDK.

I think this might me the reason :)

Comment: can you make it a little bit clearer ? you mean RecyclerView , CardView is not compatible with SDK  < 20  ? if yes then check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29982535/android-supportcardview-recyclerviewlibrary-in-older-versions-with-target-kit

Comment: In your dependencies your have `com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0` if you are changing the compile SDK version from 23 to 19 then try to change the v7 support to `com.android.support:cardview-v7:19.4.0`

Comment: have you tried changing your dependencies `com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0` to `com.android.support:cardview-v7:19.4.0` while compiling it with SDK 19??

Answer (score -1):

go to project structure and click on add library dependency and choose com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1 press ok it will solve your problem. Click on below links to undersatnd

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhYIN.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDCGN.png