# Converting AAR to JAR in Android

Tags: android, jar, aar

I have designed a android project in Eclipse,But its need a library file which is AAR format.I have tried to convert AAR to JAR by following below provided steps

```
Extract the AAR file using standard zip extract
Find the classes.jar file in the extracted files
Rename it to your liking and use the wanted jar file in your project
```

But its not working out.is there any other way to do this conversion OR is there any way to add aar file as library project to Eclipse ADT

Comment: can you please tell me library name?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417419/how-to-convert-aar-to-jar

Comment: CustomBrowser library provided by payumoney people

Answer (score 3):

> is there any way to add aar file as library project to Eclipse ADT

No, except perhaps if you switch to using Maven for your Eclipse builds.

> is there any other way to do this conversion

You have to try to convert the AAR into a more-or-less regular Android library project. [This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449344/using-android-support-v7-widget-cardview-in-my-project-eclipse/24468117#24468117) provides a recipe, and [this blog post of mine](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/03/consuming-aars-eclipse.html) provides more information on the process.

However, using Eclipse with the ADT plugin is no longer a good idea, as official support for that will end by the end of the year.