# Android Studio Library project - .jar creation in addition/instead of .aar

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, library-project, aar

I have an Android App set up as an eclipse project and associated library projects. I create jars from these library projects and share them with customers and/or plug in into my app's libs folder.

Now, I am moving my entire project to Android Studio and I notice that the library projects in Android Studio create .aar files by default.

I am not sure if it will be an easy task to request customers to start using .aar, so I want to stick with .jar files.

I was wondering if there are any detailed tutorials for creating .jar files from an Android Studio project. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: If the aar library doesn't use resources, a simple conversion would work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417419/how-to-convert-aar-to-jar  For more complex libraries, take a look at this blog post from @CommonsWare: https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/03/consuming-aars-eclipse.html  Which references this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449344/using-android-support-v7-widget-cardview-in-my-project-eclipse/24468117#24468117

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I do not require any resources. I know that I can do a simple conversion. I was hoping to automate it so that everytime someone builds the Android Studio project, build.gradle is set up such that the output is a mylibrary.jar file. (I do not want to add external scripts to do this)