# Extra activity entries in manifest due to third party library

Tags: android, build, android-manifest

I'm using google-play-services library in my app which is a eclipse project. 
When final apk creating, it's containing some extra entries in manifest.xml file which is showing as containing ads alert when publishing app.
Extra entries showing like -

```
<activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

How could we ignore/remove these entries from final apk?

```
<activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

I think `tools:node="remove"`can be used for gradle build or will work for eclipse build as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is added by `admob` library. So if you don't want it and you don't want your app to contain ads, you should exclude `admob` from your project.

`tools:node="remove"` is for removing unwanted permission from other libraries that is used in your project and yes, it won't work in eclipse.

**UPDATE:**

Seems that you are using an old version of `google-play-services` which contains all modules as a single `.jar` file. I suggest that you find out which module of `google-play-service` you need for this project and only add that one with it's dependencies  instead of adding all modules of `google-play-services` as a single jar. And this version you are using possibly is version `8.4.0` of `google-play-service` (or even older than it) so it is much better to use one of the newer versions.

For using only the module that your project needs and using a latest version of it, you should do as follows. Let's assume that you just need 'play-services-maps`. So you go to

```
<android-sdk-folder>/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps
```

and open one of the recent versions like `11.0.4` (or less but I suggest to choose one of 10+ versions) and get the `.aar` file and add it to your eclipse project (if you don't know how to use `.aar` file in eclipse [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24468117/3341752)). Also open the `play-services-maps-x.x.x.pom` file to see what is the other library that `maps` needs (which are `play-services-base` and `play-services-basement` in this example) and go to their folder and add their `.aar` files to your project too and check their `.pom` files as well to include tehir dependencies.

Yes, it is kind of tedious job, but it is the way to add this gradle-based-distributed libraries to eclipse.

Comment: Hi Merka, I don't have `admob` library added in my project. only library used in app is `google-play-services_lib`.

Comment: @Pankaj I edited my answer based on your comment. It will be better if you add this comment as additional hint to your question.